# Data in global variable not getting updated

Tags: node.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
     var names = [];
     connection.query('SELECT * from shares', function(err, rows) {
        if (err)
          console.log('error in execution...');
        else {
          names = []
          for ( var i in rows) {
            names.push(rows[i].title);
          }
        }
     });
    //var names = heroes.map(function(p) { return p.name; });
     console.log('names : ' + names);
    res.render('index', { heroes: names });
};
```

In the above code, I want to print the value of name at the end of the function. Its printing nothing. Can somebody tell me how to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the res.render and the console log in the function callback from your query. At the time you call console.log the database hasn't returned the values, because it's asynchronous.

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
     var names = [];
     connection.query('SELECT * from shares', function(err, rows) {
        if (err)
          console.log('error in execution...');
        else {
          names = []
          for ( var i in rows) {
            names.push(rows[i].title);
          }
         console.log('names : ' + names);
         res.render('index', { heroes: names });
        } 
     });
    //var names = heroes.map(function(p) { return p.name; });

};
```

Comment: You might want to respond with a something in the `if(err)` bit as well, otherwise your webpage will just hang if there is a problem in the database.